# Trying to use dpkg within a folder only on files with the keyword 'mono' in the title

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, dpkg

I'm currently trying to install mono using dpkg, and all the other files within the same folder using apt-get, I know I need to use some form of this:

```
sudo grep 'mono' | dpkg -R --install >/dev/null
```

however there are too many unknowns for me to complete it and fill in whatever blanks there may be, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls | grep "mono" | sudo xargs dpkg -R --install >/dev/null
```

The ls will only give files from the current directory. You could also use `ls -d *mono*` instead of the ls and grep, but I think the ls and grep is easier to understand

The grep is as you had, but now has input from the ls to grep on. You can try `ls | grep "mono"` to see what files it selects.

Then the sudo is moved to the dpkg part of the script to make dpkg run as root. The way you had it grep runs as root and dpkg as your user

The xargs will take whatever input you had, and put it after the next command. It will take command line length limits in account and execute multiple dpkg commands if the command line gets too big. Note that if your files have spaces in their names, xargs will see the space as start of a new file and you will have problems. There are solutions to that, but really, the easiest solution is to have no files with spaces.

In this example, lets say there are 2 files from the grep "mono1.deb and "mono2.deb" the command executed will be `dpkg -R --install mono1.deb mono2.deb`. If for some reason you want only one deb per dpkg execution you can change it to `...xargs -n1 dpkg...` and it will run `dpkg -R --install mono1.deb` and also `dpkg -R --install mono2.deb`

The `>/dev/null` make sure you won't get any output. Note that you will still get the errors though!

Comment: how about `sudo find . -name '*mono*' -exec dpkg -Ri {} +` or simply `sudo dpkg -Ri *mono*`?

Comment: @LéaGris Sounds like good options. I did read what OP tried and just tried to make that work. Make it an answer and people can vote for it.

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked perfectly, and also thank you for breaking it down, I'm new to shell scripting so its a big help!